# Pystata config on linux

Tags: python, config, stata

I've trying to run the following commands in spyder and jupyter-notebook to use with stata.

```
import stata_setup
stata_setup.config('/home/goodMan/Downloads/STATA/', 'se')

import sys
sys.path.append('/home/goodMan/Downloads/STATA/utilities')
from pystata import config
config.init('se')
```

In fact there is no error, but the kernel dies by some reason that I don't know. [Source](https://www.stata.com/python/pystata/install.html#method-2-adding-pystata-to-sys-path)

I'll really apreciate your support. Thanks

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious. Are you able to use your Stata installation outside of Python?

Comment: For sure, by using ```./xstata``` through the terminal.